# Draw dashed outer line with D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have been trying to figure out how I can draw a line with a dashed outline like the example below with D3.js. Any tips on how I can accomplish this?

[image]

**Edit:**
I am doing this with a map so I cannot just create my own lines as they are defined in the map data. Can I draw the line twice with an offset somehow?

Comment: draw a polyline or path for both lines with a dashed stroke.

Comment: I am actually trying to draw this in a map, so I cannot manually make my own polylines/paths. I guess I need to draw it twice somehow with an offset?

Comment: You might need to provide a fiddle. If it was a line as defined like a line chart it would be easy. However, if your drawing like a road or a walking path then you need a different approach since your using the `d3.geo.path()`  instead of the `d3.svg.line()`. We will probably need some more detail in order to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly as what you need

I tried to solve this problem using pattern in svg.

First create a def and make a patter inside like this:

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="cyril" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
      <path d="M 2, 0 l 0, 4" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="darkorange" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
      <path d="M 0,2 l 4,0" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="darkorange" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Now make a complex path and fill the stroke with the pattern like this

```
svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M 100 350 q 150 -300 300 0")
  .attr("stroke", "url(#cyril)")
  .style("stroke-width", "10")
  .style("fill", "none");
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/gkccm96L/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that is fills the entire line and not just the outline. Mayby there is a way to mask out the center using patterns?

Comment: yeah you are right This is not a solution. I tried something thought of sharing it thats all :)